# When and how to use mysql ReplicationConnection and ReplicationDriver?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, replication

Can `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnection` and `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` be used directly to split a read-only connection to one of the replication data sources when using a master-slaves topology?

As the javadoc of Connector/J states, the `ReplicationConnection` is a

> Connection that opens **two** connections, one to a replication master, and
>   another to one or more slaves, and decides to use master when the connection
>   is not read-only, and use slave(s) when the connection is read-only.

So, I just wonder if it really works as expected, since we cannot benefit from the master-slaves topology which releases the burden of many read-only connections to the master node.

When I looked inside the source code, I found that the connections to the master and the slave have been both established in the constructor, which means that each read-only operation will not only just connect to the slave, but also connect to the master without any communication, and to be short, it doesn't release the burden of the master.

So, is it correct to use the `ReplicationConnection` in this way? Or maybe it is just used in other scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that it doesn't release the burden of the master? It's true that it will do a connection but it will not issue any queries against the master while the connection is in read-only mode `Connection.setReadOnly(true)`.

So if your application puts your connection in and out of read-only mode for all calls it will in face relieve the master of all those reads while still doing all the writes there.

You can make sure it does the right thing by turning on the [general log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html) (ie query log) on both machines and see where each query goes.

Comment: Since there is always a connection limitation of a single MySQL instance, will it happens that the master node could not afford any more connection but the slaves could, since the master handles connections n times as many as each slaves does. (where n equals the number of the slaves). Or, as you said if I don't misunderstand, it is resource the SQL execution consumes (including query) but not the socket connection limitation of a single node that is the bottleneck, so that we need to deploy more replicas to achieve high availability.

Comment: You are correct in that the master needs to offer enough connections for each client but it should be no problem to have max number of connections in the range of thousands...